# use javascript or css to make paper button noink

Tags: javascript, css, polymer, polymer-1.0

So I'm using javascript to generate `paper-buttons` like so:

```
function createButtons(dieDefaults) {
for(var i = 0; i < dieDefaults.length; i++) {
    var btn = document.createElement("paper-button");

    var txt = document.createTextNode(dieDefaults[i]);
    btn.className += "smallButton";
    btn.onclick = function() {
        document.getElementById("sidesInput").value = this.firstChild.nodeValue;
        checkInput(btn);
    }
    btn.appendChild(txt);
    document.getElementById("dieDefaultDiv").appendChild(btn);
}
}
```

So I use `var btn = document.createElement("paper-button");` to create a paper-button. How do I add `noink`or `raised` to this? I'm also willing to use css to style them all, but `--paper-button-raised: true;` in:

```
  paper-button{
color: var(--paper-blue-grey-100);
background: var(--paper-indigo-500);
--paper-button-raised: true;}
```

doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set `noink` and `raised` like any other property on `btn`:

```
btn.noink = true;
btn.raised = true;
```

```html
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+1.7.0/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
  <link rel="import" href="paper-button/paper-button.html">
</head>
<body>
  <script>
    HTMLImports.whenReady(function() {
      var btn = document.createElement('paper-button');
      btn.textContent = 'Hello';
      btn.noink = true;
      btn.raised = true;
      btn.onclick = function() {
        console.log('clicked');
      };
      document.body.appendChild(btn);
    });
  </script>
</body>
```